# mysql regex inverse (only for use by REGEXP)

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a regex in mysql and wanna to inverse it. but don't wanna use NOT REGEXP. Negative lookbehind (?![something]) is not working in mysql.
Exactly I wanna find rows that not -1 only with REGEXP.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "rows that not -1 only with REGEXP"?

Comment: it means rows that not have value = -1. in regex it can be '^((?!-1).*)$' but it isn't work in mysql

Comment: Let's stop playing games. Provide your actual regular expression and ask for an expression which would be its negation.

Comment: If you want to find rows which aren't equal to -1, what's wrong with `!= -1`?

Comment: because I work on a close source framework and in it query is WHERE field REGEXP '[some_regex]' and I only can change the regex. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exactly regex for me is `^([^-][^1]|-[^1]|[^-]1|.?|.{3,})$`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match values which are not `-1`, without using `NOT REGEXP`, you could use:

```
^([^-][^1]|.?|.{3,})$
```