# MySQL - exclude text in regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to find all the records in a specific column that include any HTML tags that are not `<br>` tags.

Examples:

Include: `text <b>text</b> more text...`

Include: `text <br> <b>text</b> more text...`

Do not include: `text <br> text <br> more text...`

I think I need to use [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), but I am not sure how to exclude the `<br>` only results.

Comment: This SO [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943215/mysql-regex-inverse-only-for-use-by-regexp) may be of help. It also makes mention on `NOT REGEXP` too.

Comment: @gwillie yes, this is similar to Casimir's method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
<([^b][^>]*|b[^r][^>]*|b)>
```

The idea is to use negated character classes to list all possibilities that are not a `<br>` tag. Since you are only looking for html tags, you can allow all the cases that don't begin with `<br`.

Comment: I assume this is elegant as it can possibly be. Thanks.